# how to implement drag-and-drop functionality in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, file, drag-and-drop, copy

Suppose I have a cocoa application with just a window and nothing in it. But if the user drags and drops a file into this window, the file will automatically be copied to a particular directory. How do I implement such a drag-and-drop functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three seconds invested in searching "cocoa drag and drop" produces the [Drag and Drop Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html). You want the "Dragging Destinations" section (since you're responding to a file dragged *to* your window. Read the documentation and try to follow along. If you get stuck, post a specific question with the code you used and the problem you encountered.

Comment: (Edited - I originally thought OP described a promise file drag)